# DOM append property causes error

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How to populate content of DOM elements after the initial append? Most of the code shown below is the DOM creation. The span segments are my four clickable elements. They all call the same function once clicked. The button calls a seperate function, which is used to reload the screen but show the next set of questions from JSON.

```
   i=0;
function myFunction(){
    //console.log('hello')
    div1=document.createElement("div");
    div1.setAttribute("class","container");
// console.log(div1)
    // for(var i=0;i<content.length;i++){
        div2=document.createElement("div");
        div2.setAttribute("class","question-card");
        div1.appendChild(div2);
 // console.log(div2)       
        h11=document.createElement("h1");
        h11.setAttribute("id","question1");
        h11.innerHTML=content[i].question;
        div2.appendChild(h11);
// console.log(h11)
        div3=document.createElement("div");
        div3.setAttribute("class","answer-choices");
        div1.appendChild(div3);
// console.log(div3)
        div4=document.createElement("div");
        div4.setAttribute("class","row1");
        div3.appendChild(div4);
// console.log(div4)
        span1=document.createElement("span");
        span1.setAttribute("class","choice1");
        span1.setAttribute("id","one");
        document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id== 'one'){//do something}
        unlocknext();


 }});
        //span1.setAttribute("onclick","choice1()");
        span1.innerHTML=content[i].options[0];
        div4.appendChild(span1);

// console.log(span5)
        button1=document.createElement("button");
        button1.setAttribute("id","btn");
        button1.setAttribute("disabled",true);
        document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id=='btn'){//do something}
        nextScreen();    
 }});
        button1.innerHTML="Next";
        div1.appendChild(button1);
    //}
// console.log(button1) 
document.body.appendChild(div1);
}
function unlocknext(){
    document.getElementById('btn').removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById('question1').innerHTML="Answer recorded, click next.";
    console.log('Unlock next')
    console.log(div1)
}

function nextScreen(){
    console.log(i);
    i++;    
    myFunction();
    console.log("NextscreenUpload")
}
```

My JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quiz game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script src="json/qubank.json"></script>
<script src="js/dynamicindex.js"></script>
</html>
```

My HTML

```
body{
    background-color: #642ca3;
    font-family: Roboto;
}
.container{
text-align: center;
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 50%;
background-color: green;
top: 40%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.question-card{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.answer-choices{
    background-color: 
}
.choice1{
    background-color: #f75c4f;
}
.choice1:hover{
    background-color: #f52f1e;
}
.choice2{
    background-color: #f23def;
}
.choice2:hover{
    background-color: #ec10e9;
}

.choice3{
    background-color: #02b6ee;
}
.choice3:hover{
    background-color: #028fbb;
}
.choice4{
    background-color: #f2ba2c;
}
.choice4:hover{
    background-color: #dda30e;
}
.row1{
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 30px;
}
.row2{
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 30px;
}
span{
    padding: 2%;
    margin: 10%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;

}
```

MY CSS

Comment: _What_ is the error?

Comment: Everytime the next button is clicked, because of append the elements are added multiple times. For ex: first time it works properly, second time it executes twice instead of just once, third time it executes 4 times. Hence the second click actually appends itself with the first time and hence executes twice. The third click similarly does 4 times.

Comment: share your html, css code also

Comment: The curly brackets don't match. There's an additional `}` after `.appendChild(div1)`. Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.